# Not collapsed css styling is applied on initial page load

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie to Angular and I'm using Bootstrap to implement a sidebar containing a vertical menu with submenus. I can toggle the visibility of the submenu content by clicking on an arrow icon.
When the arrow is pointing down the submenu shows and when it is pointing right, it is hidden. So Initially the arrows should be pointing to the right. If clicked the node is expanded and the arrow will be pointing right.

The problem when the application is loaded the arrow is pointing down when they should be pointing to the right.

Example used: https://www.codeply.com/p/Nkp8O77PFS

***Customized code:***

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
<div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-blue">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
      <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Logs</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle ">
            <i class="fs-4 bi-bootstrap"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Logs </span></a>  
          <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
            <li class="w-100">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">History</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-table"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Actions</span></a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-grid"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm inline">Products</span> </a>
         <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
           <li class="w-100">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
     <hr>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

***CSS styling:***

```
.nav-link[data-bs-toggle].collapsed:after { //Initially collapsed item so arrow right
    content: url(../../assets/images/chevron-right.svg);
    color: white !important;
 }
.nav-link[data-bs-toggle]:not(.collapsed):after { //Not collapsed item so arrow down
    content: url(../../assets/images/chevron-down.svg);
    color:  white !important;
 }
```

***Initial wrong Result:***
[image]

***Initial expected Result:***

[image]

***Clicking Arrow expanded node:***

[image]

Ps: the problem exists only initially.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first CSS selector is never triggered, because the class `collapsed` does not exist initially, before the element is actually toggled.

So, add class `collapsed` to the elements with submenus, which will then make the first selector work as expected on initial load:

```
<a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle collapsed">


<a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle collapsed">
```

I've modified your code to make it reproducible here:

```css
.nav-link[data-bs-toggle].collapsed:after { 
    content: "\25b8";
    color: black !important;
 }
.nav-link[data-bs-toggle]:not(.collapsed):after { 
    content: "\25be";
    color:  black !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
<div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-blue">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
      <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Logs</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          
          <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle collapsed">
            <i class="fs-4 bi-bootstrap"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Logs </span></a>  
          <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
            <li class="w-100">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">History</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-table"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Actions</span></a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle collapsed">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-grid"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm inline">Products</span> </a>
         <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
           <li class="w-100">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
          <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
     <hr>
     
     

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>



    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```